# Drawing multiple double headed arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the following code to draw multiple double-headed arrows.

When I used one single `\draw` command, only the last line has double-headed arrow.

But when I used multiple `\draw` commands, all lines have double-headed arrows. Why was that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (0,2) -- +(0:1.2cm) (2,2) -- +(0:1.2cm) (4,2) -- +(0:1.2cm);

\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (0,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex']  (2,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (4,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you replace in the first `draw` command `--` by edge, i.e. `\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (0,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (2,2) edge
+(0:1.2cm) (4,2) -- +(0:1.2cm);`, you'll get the same result as in the second row,

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace in the first `\draw` command the first two `--` by `edge`, i.e. `\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (0,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (2,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (4,2) -- +(0:1.2cm);`, you'll get the same result as in the second row.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex'-latex'] (0,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (2,2) edge
+(0:1.2cm) (4,2) -- +(0:1.2cm);

\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (0,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex']  (2,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex' -latex'] (4,1) -- +(0:1.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The results are different since in the first row of your example you have just one path, and instruct Ti*k*Z to insert arrow heads at its start and end. On the other hand, an `edge` is a new path, so each of these edges will have arrow heads at their start and end positions. I personally do not work with edges that much because I find them slightly confusing. To see that, replace *all* `--` by `edge`s (as I did in the first version of my comment),

```
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex'-latex'] (0,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (2,2) edge +(0:1.2cm) (4,2) edge +(0:1.2cm);
```

Then you'll get

[image]

There is an excess vertical arrow, which you noted yourself. This is because there is essentially an empty path consisting just of one point, `(4,2)`. Why this is the point Ti*k*Z takes the path to be, and not, say, `(0,2)` I do not 100% understand, but this is the reason why I do not like to use edges too much and think your serious of `\draw` commands is cleaner.

Comment: @Hany You're welcome!